# Best way to trace what caused a refreshing computer

Tags: windows

My computer has an irritating behavior lately. It refreshes every 5 seconds. This is visible because you can see that an application window is flickering and when you select from a combo box, the drop down returns back when refresh is triggered again. I tried closing all open applications to trace what may have caused the refreshing cycle but found that it didn't came from the applications. Stopping windows services one by one is not a good idea. Is there a way to trace which application/service/background process is invoking the refresh?

Comment: Is the whole screen flickering or just a window? Do you see the icons on the desktop get redrawn or is it more like someone turns the screen black or white for a moment?

Comment: Which Windows version?

Comment: @Aaron The application windows of my Delphi IDEs (Delphi 5, 7, 2010) are flickering. I don't see that the icons are being redrawn.
@Harry I use Windows XP

Comment: Is it flickering white, grey or black? Does the flicker cover the whole screen or only part of it? Does something change if you move the app windows into a different corner of the screen? Is the whole window flickering or only some part of it? What happens if you move the window while it flickers?

Comment: Or can you create a video and post that on Youtube or something?

Answer (score 0):

That's a setting of your video card, *Refresh frequency*. If you can't set it higher, consider updating your drivers.

Comment: I don't think it's the refresh rate because the interval is 5 seconds and also affects the selection in combo box